# Identify latest status of a record and when it was last changed

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Thanks for providing oppurtunity to explain my issue. 
I have a table which captures the latest status of all patients admitted to the hospital. (table structure with sample data is below). The requirement is that, the latest status of each patient should be shown and the time when the latest status appeared.

```
 ID | PatientId |       Status       |       TimeOfStatusChange 
----------
 1  |    1 |           Admitted |            2019-07-01 10:00 AM
----------
2  |    1   |         In Triage      |       2019-07-01 10:15 AM
----------
3  |    1       |     In Triage  |          2019-07-01 10:30 AM
----------
4   |   1   |         Surgery Scheduled  |   2019-07-01 11:00 AM
----------
5   |   1      |      In Triage     |        2019-07-01 11:30 AM
----------
6   |   1    |        Surgery Scheduled  |   2019-07-01 12:01 PM
----------
7    |  1    |        Surgery Scheduled   |  2019-07-01 12:30 PM
----------
```

So, in this example, a patient got admitted at 10 AM. his latest status is "surgery Scheduled" and that last change of that status was "12:01 PM". So, the expected output is:

```
PatientId  |    RecentStatus  |     TimeWhenStatusAppeared
----------
1    |          Surgery Scheduled  |  2019-07-01 12:01 PM
```

Retrieving latest status was pretty straight forward and the query that helps is:

```
select PatientId, Status from StatusTest s1 where s1.ID = 
    ( select max(ID) from StatusTest s2 where s1.PatientId = s2.PatientId)
```

But now the issue is retrieving the last change of this status is a challenge. Any one who can help, much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a sub-query here. A `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function will give you everything you need in one go.

The `ORDER BY` clause breaks out your results into groups by `PatientID`, and then the `TOP (1) WITH TIES` clause limits the rows returned to the most recent entry, based in the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` sub-clause.

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  PatientID,
  Status,
  TimeOfStatusChange AS TimeWhenStatusAppeared
FROM
  StatusTest
ORDER BY 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY TimeOfStatusChange DESC);
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply. Though your query returns the latest Status, but it returns the time when the current changed happened. So your query returned: 1, Surgery Scheduled, 2019-07-01 12:30:00.000. But i am expecting: 1, Surgery Scheduled, 2019-07-01 12:01:00.000. I hope i am clear. If not, i can explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

All
The following solution worked for me:

/*****

- Select all columns and new column to find the previous status for
- Deduct if any change of status happened by comparing current status
  with previous status column
- Introduce row number to identify the latest record in each group
- Finally retrieve the latest from each status change for a given Patient

******/

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT StatusDateTime, PatientId, LevelOfCare,
LAG(LevelOfCare) OVER (ORDER BY StatusDateTime) AS [PREVIOUS]
FROM StatusTest),
ALL_STATS AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE LevelOfCare <> [PREVIOUS]
),
CTE_ROW_NUM AS (
SELECT  PatientId, StatusDateTime, LevelOfCare,
row_number() over(partition by PatientId order by PatientId,StatusDateTime desc) as RowNum
 FROM ALL_STATS 
)
select *
from CTE_ROW_NUM
where RowNum = 1;
```

Please let me know for any questions